# Android studio said my flutter sdk version is 2.0.2 even though I had upgraded the flutter version

Tags: flutter, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aii2w.jpg)
Hi guys, I imported a project downloaded online. I had upgrade all the dependencies but I'm unable to run pub get because it said my flutter sdk version is low. However I had actually upgrade the flutter version using flutter --upgrade in flutter console

Comment: can you also add `pubspec.yaml` details  `environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`

Comment: Hi, I had tried it but an error appeared 

*The current Flutter SDK version is 2.0.2.

Because food_delivery_app depends on flutter_html >=2.1.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=2.2.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because food_delivery_app depends on flutter_html >=2.1.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=2.2.0, version solving failed.)*

Btw I tried to use flutter upgrade in android studio terminal but it said flutter is not recognized even though I had set the path in environment variable